# CRM Dynamics 2016: Upload PDF Template

Tags: templates, pdf, crm, microsoft-dynamics

CRM Dynamics 2016 only allows to upload Excel and Word files as templates.
For the solution I am building I need to be able to upload a PDF so the users can choose it later on a custom dialog.

Is there a way this can be achieved? Maybe some add-on?

Answer (score 2):

There are two third party products of note that are worth investigating and provide exactly this functionality.

[DocumentsCorePack](http://www.mscrm-addons.com/Products/DocumentsCorePack) from MS-CRM Addons.

[XperiDo](http://www.xperido.com/) from Invenso.